# Android camera preview remove green screen?

Tags: android, image-processing, camera, video-processing

The user will use the front camera, with a green cloth on the wall  (chromatic background )

How is possible to access the preview data and change it: remove the selected color with a tolerance?  Ex green, tolerance 65%

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    int width = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
    int height = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;

    YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(), width, height, null);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 50, out);

    byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loopback)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
}
```

http://jylee-world.blogspot.ro/2014/12/a-tutorial-of-androidhardwarec

> We need simple tutorials. There is no good sample code even in
>   http://developer.android.com .

Comment: have you try any code

Comment: @sohail absoluthly useless comment

Answer (score 0):

Use Bitmap.getPixel(int x, int y) to get the color of each pixel and bitmap.setPixel() to change the color to what you like

```
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
int R = Color.red(pixel);
int G = Color.blue(pixel);
int B = Color.green(pixel);

if G == //(range of green values)
    bitmap.setPixel(x, y, color)
```